# Angular6 - HttpClient cache a request when using socket.io-client

Tags: angular, socket.io, xmlhttprequest

After add **socket.io-client** library to my Angular 6 app, `HttpClient` returns same `json` body for each request to same endpoint (event when query params is different).

I think the problem is in the `HttpClient` service because the `fetch` method works normally.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: No code to share?

Comment: @KyleBurkett Is there a way to create demo with websockets?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to avoid this by adding a parameter with random value or current date in the URL, like `t=Date.now()` or, casually, I found that this stopped happening if I made a patch request.

```
this.socket.on('connect', () => {
  this.socket.emit('authentication', accessToken);
  this._http.patch('', {}).toPromise().then();
});
```

Neither way is good practice, but it can work momentarily.